# How could i execute the downloaded file (java)

Tags: java

1. I have a basic java program that downloads the file from a link.
2. I need to make it execute the file in mentioned directory.
3. I need it to ensure that the file has downloaded.

4.It would be nice if someone could help me.

5.Thanks for anyone willing to help me out.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLReader {

    public static void copyURLToFile(URL url, File file) {
        
        try {
            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            if (file.exists()) {
                if (file.isDirectory())
                    throw new IOException("File '" + file + "' is a directory");
                
                if (!file.canWrite())
                    throw new IOException("File '" + file + "' cannot be written");
            } else {
                File parent = file.getParentFile();
                if ((parent != null) && (!parent.exists()) && (!parent.mkdirs())) {
                    throw new IOException("File '" + file + "' could not be created");
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }

            input.close();
            output.close();
            
            System.out.println("File '" + file + "' downloaded successfully!");
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        String sUrl = "http://localhost:8000/TestFile/file.exe";
        
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        
        File file = new File("C:/Temp/file.exe");
        
        URLReader.copyURLToFile(url, file);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, what file you want to execute? Are those Java files? Ideally, it's a task for bash script.

Comment: Once you've downloaded and saved the file you can use use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run a command.